# Стандарт кодирования Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework-2, php

Доброго времени суток!
Коллеги, подскажите, где описан стандарт кодирования Zend Framework 2? Есть описания стандарта [здесь](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/coding-standard.html). Но, как я понимаю, этот стандарт уже устарел, по крайней мере в части правил именования переменных. Например, в коде самого Zend Framework 2 нельзя найти private-члены, имена который начинаются на символ "_", хотя в Zend Framework 1 это правила обязательно.

Comment: @morin, вам стоило бы пройтись по заданным вами вопросам и отметить правильные

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: @morin, нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом. Чем больше ваших вопросов будут иметь отмеченных ответов, тем чаще вам будут отвечать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, сможете найти что-то полезное [тут](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Coding+Standards). 
Если не откроется (как у меня), то ищите в кеше Google.

О приватных методах и свойствах теперь говорится, что они могут использовать нижнее подчеркивание, но не желательно из-за усложнения рефакторинга с изменением модификатора доступа.

Comment: То что надо, спасибо!